# 64bit OS with a 32bit application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7

I created an application that runs on a 32bit OS fine, but every 64bit OS I have tried it doesn't seem to work.

I'm creating an application that allows you to change the background image of the login screen in Windows 7. To achieve this my application needs to create a folder in the System32 directory, and on the 64bit OS it doesn't seem to want to create it. I don't get an error, and it doesn't throw an exception. It just doesn't seem to create the folder.

The 64bit OS has a different System32 folder 'Windows\SysWOW64\', so should I be writing to that instead? I'm a little confused on what the 64bit OS is doing, so would be great if someone could clear it up and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Code for making the directory:

```
path = DriveLabel += @"Windows\System32\Oobe\info\backgrounds\";

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your application is running with the appropriate privileges? System32 is going to be a protected directory.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used?

Comment: Yes, I am running on administrator account. And at the start of the program, I check to see if the user is an administrator.

Comment: For everyone who is as confused as I was about this, [read this article](http://www.withinwindows.com/2009/03/15/windows-7-to-officially-support-logon-ui-background-customization/), I *think* milkboat is trying to write a application to manage images in the %windir%\system32\oobe\info folder.

Comment: @Milkboat a small tangentental note, the way you find the windows folder is bad, A user can install windows to whatever folder you want, Use the `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Windows)` and it will always point to the install directory of windows running on the current machine.

Answer (score 2):

On a 64 bit OS the system32 directory is for 64 bit processes and the SysWOW64 directory is for 32 bit processes. Read that sentence one more time since it is rather counter-intuitive!

The [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ensures that a process that attempts to access system32 is redirected to the appropriate directory.

If your process is 32 bit then when it writes to system32, the redirector results in the file/directory being created under SysWOW64.

**Update 1** Apparently UAC is disabled. In this case your writes to system32 from a 32 bit process will be producing output under SysWOW64. Rather than checking that UAC is disabled, you should just add the `requireAdministrator` option to your manifest.

**Update 2** In the comments you state that you want to change the logon screen's background. In order to do that you'll need to work with the native 64 bit directory since Explorer is a 64 bit process on a 64 bit OS. You have a number of options to achieve that:

1. Target AnyCPU so that you run as a 64 bit process under 64 bit OS. This is easily the simplest approach.
2. Write to \Windows\sysnative if you find yourself running on a 64 bit OS. This the sneaky way for a 32 bit process to name the otherwise un-speakable 64 bit system32 folder.
3. Disable the file system redirector (not really to be recommended).

Comment: Windows 7 was on all the machines I have tested it on. I also checked to see if UAC was disabled.

Comment: I have to ask, why are you creating folders in system32. That's against all known guidelines of reasonable practice.

Comment: I'm creating an application that allows you to change the background image of the login screen in Windows 7. To do that you need to create a specific directory and move an image there.

Comment: My latest update covers this now. The information missing from the question is what is contained in your comment above, namely that you are after the 64 bit native system32.

Answer (score 1):

Now that there has been more details provided [David Heffernan's 2nd update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141715/64bit-os-with-a-32bit-application/8141842#8141842) is the correct solution. I will leave this answer here for other people finding this page with a similar question, but his advice is what you need to do for this spcific case.

---

**Original Answer:**

The system32 folder on a 64 bit windows os is only for 64 bit dll's and executables, the sysWOW64 is for the 32 bit versions. This is done so programs don't break that are expecting to get 32 bit dll's and will end up being given 64 bit dll's. Windows detects that a 32 bit program is trying to write or read to the System32 folder and redirects it to the new folder. Go ahead and use it as is, just be aware that if someone is navigating in explorer they need to go to the SysWOW64 folder to access your files. [Here is a MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249.aspx) going in to writing 32 bit applications on 64 bit windows. The key parts to look at are the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx) and the [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232.aspx)

There are some other automatic redirections with files and registry keys you should be aware of if you are working on modern operating systems. These happen because people where writing applications with the assumption they had administrator privileges for so long, microsoft did not want to break everything when they cracked the whip on with account privileges with vista and win 7. [See this blog post.](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx)

Also to drive home David Heffernan's point. I would put money on whatever you are trying to write to the System32 folder should not go there. Please explain more what you are trying to do with that folder? If you are just wanting machine local data you should be using [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx)

```
string pathToMyDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData, MyAppFolderName));
```

Comment: But using the program as is, doesn't work. It doesn't create the folder in the directory. Should I be checking to see if the OS is 64bit and then write to the SysWOW64 folder?

Comment: No! Read about the file system redirector. 32 bit process accesses of system32 are redirected to SysWOW64.